# Why is XLSX not showing as an option to download my table when configuring the view of my Workshop App?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-workshop

I am trying to download the backing dataset of a chart in Workshop as an XLSX file.

I have an object table in a workshop module that I am trying to download as an XLSX file. In other Workshops I am able to do this by right clicking on the table. But in this one it only downloads as a CSV when I use this method.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Objects stored in Phonograph are automatically downloaded as an XLSX file when you export them by right clicking on a table. However, if your table has fields generated by variables in workshop these derived fields are not stored in Phonograph, causing the CSV default instead.

To overcome this issue you can export using a button group. Set up a button group to export on click. Then specify your object set and the properties you would like to see exported. This will automatically export as an XLSX file.
[image: Button settings for download]